# Can the performance of this LEFT OUTER JOIN be improved with an index?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I run an image hosting website and I have tables for images, for users, and a new one that represents a many-to-many relationship, called `collaborators`. An image can have many collaborators (users).

I have the following query running on Postgresql:

```
SELECT image.id
FROM image
LEFT OUTER JOIN collaborators ON (image.id = collaborators.image_id)
WHERE (image.user_id = 999 OR collaborators.user_id = 999)
```

In plain English, I'm trying to find all images where user `999` is either the `user_id` or in the `collaborators` table.

However, on my database with about 100k users and 600k images, and only a handful of entries in the `collaborators` table to far, this is extremely slow (over 4 seconds).

This is the EXPLAIN ANALYZE:

```
Hash Right Join  (cost=107937.02..110540.78 rows=3318 width=4) (actual time=2928.556..4428.901 rows=25 loops=1)
  Hash Cond: (collaborators.image_id = image.id)
  Filter: ((image.user_id = 999) OR (collaborators.user_id = 999))
  Rows Removed by Filter: 653094
  ->  Seq Scan on collaborators  (cost=0.00..30.40 rows=2040 width=8) (actual time=0.013..0.016 rows=8 loops=1)
  ->  Hash  (cost=97220.01..97220.01 rows=653201 width=8) (actual time=2905.239..2905.240 rows=653119 loops=1)
        Buckets: 131072  Batches: 16  Memory Usage: 2623kB
        ->  Seq Scan on image  (cost=0.00..97220.01 rows=653201 width=8) (actual time=0.016..1689.448 rows=653119 loops=1)
Planning time: 0.228 ms
Execution time: 4429.183 ms
```

Please keep in mind that I don't have much control over the SQL query: this is generated by Django and I already posted a minimal version that reproduces the problem (I know of course that the problem is with the JOIN on `collaborators` because it's new).

Do I have any options in terms of database indexes, to improve the performance of this query?

Thanks!

Comment: "keep in mind that I don't have much control over the SQL query": that is never an excuse. Either teach the ORM to generate the correct query or use raw SQL. The database is not in the business of magically fixing everything an ORM messes up. You will have to rewrite the query using `UNION ALL`.

Comment: While one can do raw SQL queries with Django, changing that would require some massive refactoring on my side and i would prefer an easier solution if available.

Comment: If I knew another solution, I would have told you...

Comment: Even given the poor plan choose, this is egregiously slow.  Do an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING off)` to see if the constant clock-probing is distorting the overall run time.

Comment: Why would replacing one query with a raw query need massive refactoring?

Comment: @jjanes I'm on Aurora Postgresql 10.2.1. Replacing one query in this case will lead to something hard to maintain in the future. Building the query uses information coming from multiple places, and hard-coding it will mean that I have to manually redo some of the same things that Django already does, and also maintain some things in two places. It would be an extreme last resort. Removing timing doesn't tell me anything new: I can actually see that the site is acting slow in production since this change...

Comment: "Removing timing doesn't tell me anything new"  I don't know what you consider to be new.  Did it still take 4.4s?

Comment: The `LEFT OUTER JOIN` in my post is the new code that is causing performance problems. The 4.4s came from a query ran on production and now the website is quieter at this hour, so I can't really compare.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us the definitions of the tables involved including indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a so-called [covering index](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-index-only-scans.html) on your `image` table:

```
ALTER TABLE image ADD INDEX user_id_id (user_id, id);
```

See how well that helps your query performance. With `collaborators` containing only a small number of rows, it will probably help a lot.

When `collaborators` grows you'll need to rerun the EXPLAIN ANALYZE and consider adding other indexes.

Read Marcus Winand's helpful e-book:  https://use-the-index-luke.com/